# Storyboard localization excludes a single file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, translation

I am facing a very obscure issue.

I've got an app that needs to be localized in three Languages, English, French, German. There's multiple localization files as I've got multiple storyboards ( each storyboard has one for each language).

Everything works great and things translate properly except for ONE file in ONE storyboard in ONE language. So this specific storyboard I call "Authentication" works for all languages except for the German one.

I've checked. the file is:

- included in all targets
- is also found in Build Phases copy phase
- has the correct name.
- has the correct formatting *(in fact i am not allowed to build at all if the formatting is not correct in this version of Xcode.)*

I am out of ideas and resorting to asking here to see if theres anything i might be missing in my series of checks.

Thanks all

Comment: Am i allowed to bump? Not sure what the rule is for long unanswered questions. If this is not allowed please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

The answer lies within my third point

- *has the correct formatting (in fact i am not allowed to build at all
  if the formatting is not correct in this version of Xcode.)*

**Beware** everyone. This might seem like it is the case but it does not apply to everything. If there's a syntactic error in the Localizable.strings file, xcode will let you know and refuse to build.

**HOWEVER** if there's a syntax error in the YourStoryboard.strings file, the process of building will go on UNHINDERED.

Since an issue in syntax was halting everything for Localizable.strings i was wrongfully assuming that such a check would take place for all translation files. It doesnt!

Hope this saves someone in the future